# What's the practical difference between `class <T extends A> { }` and a `class { }` that uses A?

Tags: java, generics

I think that, for the most part, I understand bounded types, and the differences between, for example, `List<? extends MyClass>`, `List<? super MyClass>` and `List<MyClass>`. But when it comes to the *implementation* of classes and generic methods, I do not understand what `<T extends MyClass>` brings to the table.

Taken from [the docs in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html):

> [...] a method that operates on numbers might only want to accept
>   instances of Number or its subclasses. This is what bounded type
>   parameters are for.
>
> ```java
> public class Box<T> {
>
>     private T t;          
>
>     public void set(T t) {
>         this.t = t;
>     }
>
>     public T get() {
>         return t;
>     }
>
>     public <U extends Number> void inspect(U u){
>         System.out.println("T: " + t.getClass().getName());
>         System.out.println("U: " + u.getClass().getName());
>     }
>
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>();
>         integerBox.set(new Integer(10));
>         integerBox.inspect("some text"); // error: this is still String!
>     }
> }
> ```

This doesn't make much sense to me. If I removed the generic from the method and made the parameter type just `Number`...

```java
    public void inspect(Number u){
        System.out.println("T: " + t.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("Second: " + u.getClass().getName());
    }
```

it would still work just fine. I don't see where I'm gaining or losing type safety, although maybe that's not the point?

Same in something like this:

```java
class A { void foo() { } }

class B extends A { void bar() { } }

class Generic<T extends B> {
    void baz(T obj) {
        obj.foo();
        obj.bar();
    }
}

// vs

class NonGeneric {
    void baz(B obj) {
        obj.foo();
        obj.bar();
    }
}
```

What's the difference between these?

Comment: If you don't need the type anywhere then there (likely) isn't much benefit. In addition to Andreas' answer, see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/227918/36403.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your examples there is no practical difference.

The main practical difference is when you have return types using the generic.

But even without that, `Generic<T extends B>` and `NonGeneric` are not the same, because if we have `class C extends B`, then `Generic<C>` is not the same as `NonGeneric`, since the `NonGeneric` would allow non-C objects in the call to `baz`, and that's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In `Generic` class `baz` function only accept `T` type value but in `NonGeneric` class you can give any object those can cast to B.
Example:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Generic<C> generic = new Generic<C>();
        generic.baz(new B()); // error
        generic.baz(new C()); // works fine
        generic.baz(new D()); // error
        NonGeneric nonGeneric = new NonGeneric();
        nonGeneric.baz(new B()); // works fine
        nonGeneric.baz(new C()); // works fine
        nonGeneric.baz(new D()); // works fine
    }

    static class A {
        void foo() {}
    }

    static class B extends A {
        void bar() {}
    }

    static class C extends B {}

    static class D extends B {}

    static class Generic<T extends B> {
        void baz(T obj) {
            obj.foo();
            obj.bar();
        }
    }

    static class NonGeneric {
        void baz(B obj) {
            obj.foo();
            obj.bar();
        }
    }
}
```